# Use SSIS RegEx Clean Transformation to Extract a Value

Tags: regex, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a transformation where I'd like to grab a value from within a string and put it in another column.

The value can be:

- a negative or positive integer from -99 to 99
- found between the words "for" and "yards" in a give string

Some examples of the string values (each line would be parsed on it's own):

- "(8:27) T.Barber right guard to SF 21 for no gain (J.Winborn B.Young). "
- "(8:06) T.Barber left tackle to SF 24 for -3 yards (J.Winborn). "
- "(8:02) G.Hearst right end to SF 26 for 2 yards (M.Barrow B.Short). "
- "(7:22) J.Garcia pass to E.Johnson to SF 27 for 1 yard (D.Jones  O.Stoutmire). "
- "(6:43) J.Garcia left end ran ob at SF 40 for 13 yards (J.Sehorn). Back to pass  rushes."
- "PENALTY on SF-S.Gragg Offensive Holding  10 yards  enforced at SF 27 - No Play."

I'm using Konesans RegEx Clean Tranformation (http://www.konesans.com/products/regexclean-transformation.aspx), but I have limited use with Regular Expression.  I was able to use an online tool to build this pattern:

```
for (?<numval>(-?\d[\d|\s]))\s?yard.
```

(link to workspace - http://regexr.com?33u0f)

[image: SSIS Transformation Configuration]

The transform is only returning NULL values in the derived column.  Any help with this transformation would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no experience with the tool and no way of testing, but try

*Match*    `(?<yards>-?\d\d?)\syard`

*Replace*  `${yards}`

Comment: It's returning numbers! However, I specifically need to have the "for " in front of the match expression.  When I add it to what you put, I'm back to getting NULLs.  Can you try and add that in?

Comment: got it!  `for\s(?<yards>-?\d\d?)\syard.`